# XML Parsing in OS X Terminal for MobileConfig file

Tags: ios, xml, plist, mdm, apple-configurator

I am working on generating (actually editing) a mobileconfig file (aka iOS profile, XML) via bash script.

The script fetch data from a MS Database and has now to inject/replace this data in my mobileconfig file (XML).

The XML file has the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>PayloadContent</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Host</key>
            <string>outlook.office365.com</string>
            <key>MailNumberOfPastDaysToSync</key>
            <integer>7</integer>
            <key>Password</key>
            <string>ActiveSyncPassword</string>
            <key>PayloadDescription</key>
            <string>Configures an Exchange account</string>
            <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
            <string>Exchange ActiveSync</string>
            <key>PayloadVersion</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>SSL</key>
            <true/>
            <key>UserName</key>
            <string>xxxxxxx@xxx.com</string>
            <key>disableMailRecentsSyncing</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>AutoJoin</key>
            <true/>
            <key>EncryptionType</key>
            <string>WPA</string>
            <key>HIDDEN_NETWORK</key>
            <true/>
            <key>IsHotspot</key>
            <false/>
            <key>Password</key>
            <string>WEPWPAWPSPEAPTLS</string>
            <key>PayloadType</key>
            <string>com.apple.wifi.managed</string>
            <key>PayloadVersion</key>
            <real>1</real>
            <key>ProxyType</key>
            <string>None</string>
            <key>SSID_STR</key>
            <string>SSID</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
```

I would like to replace the WiFi Password but also ActiveSync "Password" fields between the < string> < /string> using any native (xmllint, sed) or non-native tool.

Can anyone please help ?

Comment: Apparently /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy would be a good alternative for editing mobileconfig (native and specifically meant to work with plist files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Editing structured data (such as XML) with plain-text tools invariably ends in misery when the file format changes in ways that nobody expects to make a difference (such as inserting benign whitespace). Instead, use a tool that parses XML properly and works on the tree, such as `xmlstarlet`.

The general form for this is

```
xmlstarlet ed -u xpath -v value filename.xml
```

Where `xpath` is an XPath expression that identifies the node you want to update, and `value` is the new value you want to give it. The magic is in constructing an XPath expression that uniquely and reliably identifies the node you want to update. The MobileConfig XML format makes this somewhat harder than usual; after discussion in the comments we ended up with

```
xmlstarlet ed -u '//dict[key[text() = "PayloadDisplayName"]/following-sibling::string[1] = "Exchange ActiveSync"]/key[text() = "Password"]/following-sibling::string[1]' -v 'abc123' filename.xml
```

The core of this is the XPath expression

```
//dict[key[text() = "PayloadDisplayName"]/following-sibling::string[1] = "Exchange ActiveSync"]/key[text() = "Password"]/following-sibling::string[1]
```

..which requires some explanation. We use the following features:

- `//dict` matches any `dict` node in the document,
- `//dict/key` matches any `key` node that is the child of a `dict` node,
- `//dict/key[text() = "Password"]` matches any `key` note that is the child of a `dict` node and contains the text `Password`,
- `//dict/key[text() = "Password"]/following-sibling` matches any following sibling node of such a `key` node, which is to say any node that is a child of the same parent and comes after the `key` node in the XML,
- `//dict/key[text() = "Password"]/following-sibling::string` matches any `string` node that is such a following sibling node, and
- `//dict/key[text() = "Password"]/following-sibling::string[1]` matches any node that is the first following sibling `string` node of such a `key` node.

We've already used a condition in `//dict/key[text() = "Password"]`; in order to find the `dict` node whose password entry is to be changed, we need more of that. The `dict` node we want to find is identified by

```
//dict[key[text() = "PayloadDisplayName"]/following-sibling::string[1] = "Exchange ActiveSync"]
```

That is a `dict` node that fulfills the condition

```
key[text() = "PayloadDisplayName"]/following-sibling::string[1] = "Exchange ActiveSync"
```

The XPath expressions in this condition are all relative to the `dict` node that's being tested, so

```
key[text() = "PayloadDisplayName"]
```

refers to a `key` subnode of that `dict` node that contains the text `PayloadDisplayName`, and

```
key[text() = "PayloadDisplayName"]/following-sibling::string[1] = "Exchange ActiveSync"
```

is true if the text in the `string` node that follows the `key` node that contains the text `PayloadDisplayName` is `Exchange ActiveSync`. So we chuck that into the simplified expression I explained above and get the full filter.

I feel compelled to point out that the structure of this XML file makes the whole thing more difficult than necessary or usual. Sanely structured XML can be handled with much simpler XPath expressions (most of the time).

Comment: Thanks Wintermute, I'll try this tool and get back to you. I'm happy to see that Brew has a bottle ready for use :)

Comment: Hey mate, your solution sounds perfect, I tried it and it works like a charm, only glitch, I have two "Password" tree (I edited my original post). Can you please advise ?

Comment: It's just a matter of encoding the selection criteria in XPath. I'm not entirely sure from the description in the edited question what your selection criteria are, though -- something like changing the password in a `dict` entry whose `PayloadDisplayName` is `Exchange ActiveSync`? Please clarify.

Comment: So, I have two <dict> trees, the first one is for WiFi settings, the second is for ActivySync settings. If I apply the command above for "Password", the command will replace both "Password" fields, while it must be different (this isn't the same passwords for both fields) I do not know if I am clear :/

Comment: Well, if it's always the first, you could use the XPath `/plist/dict/array/dict[1]/key[text() = "Password"]/following-sibling::string[1]`, but I'm not sure I'd want to depend on it. The question is: How do I reliably identify the `dict` node that contains the password you want to change?

Comment: I'm thinking of something along the lines of `'//dict[key[text() = "PayloadDisplayName"]/following-sibling::string[1] = "Exchange ActiveSync"]/key[text() = "Password"]/following-sibling::string[1]'`, that would identify the Password string node from a dict whose PayloadDisplayName is "Exchange ActiveSync". Many things are possible here, it's a question of what reliably and uniquely identifies the node in question.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this

```
sed -r "s#(<string>)SSID_STR(</string>)#\1AMD\2#g" File
```

For inplace substitution:

```
sed -i -r "s#(<string>)SSID_STR(</string>)#\1AMD\2#g" File
```

`(`, `)` are used for grouping. `\1` and `\2` stands for the `first` and `second` such groups. 
Replace AMD with your actual content. similarly, u can do for Password.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, ideally I would look for a xml specific parsing tool